# Laravel POST from public folder HTTP 500

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue where I want to get POST data to send to a External DB (Not the issue) but, I am receiving an error HTTP 500. Below is the simple code and the directory of the file is in the Public folder in the root of my laravel install.

```
<?php
include_once '../../../config/DB.php';
$DBConnect = getDatabaseConnection();
$id = $_POST("id");
$id2 = $_POST("id2");
odbc_exec($DBConnect,"insert into table (id,shelf) values (".$id.",".$id2.")");
?>
```

I believe my issue to be where the file is located but, I can navigate to it I just cannot seem to send POST data from it.

Comment: Check the access.log on that server / machine. What does it say?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. You can also check the logs in `storage/logs` to see if there's anything there.

Comment: I do have a log file for today but, it doesn't have anything specifically for this issue.

Comment: Your title suggests that you are in a Laravel project. Why do you include_once and use odbc_exec instead of following the Laravel way?

Comment: What is the Laravel way on include and odbc protocol

Comment: It's all documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database). I suggest reading the Laravel docs on how to make database queries, as it appears to me that you are complicating matters, which might lead to the problem you are observing. E.g. you would include classes via `use` and use the database facade `DB` or your own models to execute queries.